# how to compare entries in numpy array with each other efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array `embed_vec` of length `tot_vec` in which each entry is a 3d vector:

```
[[ 0.52483319  0.78015841  0.71117216]
 [ 0.53041481  0.79462171  0.67234534]
 [ 0.53645428  0.80896727  0.63119403]
 ..., 
 [ 0.72283509  0.40070804  0.15220522]
 [ 0.71277758  0.38498613  0.16141834]
 [ 0.70221445  0.36918032  0.17370776]]
```

For each of the elements in this array, I want to find out the number of other entries which are "close" to that entry. By close, I mean that the distance between two vectors is less than a specified value `R`. For this, I must compare all the possible pairs in this array with each other and then find out the number of close vectors for each of the vectors in the array. So I am doing this:

```
p = np.zeros(tot_vec) # This contains the number of close vectors
for i in range(tot_vec-1):
    for j in range(i+1, tot_vec):
        if np.linalg.norm(embed_vec[i]-embed_vec[j]) < R:
            p[i] += 1
```

However, this is extremely inefficient because I have two nested python loops and for larger array sizes, this takes forever. If this were in C++ or Fortran, it wouldn't have been a great issue. My question is, can one achieve the same thing using numpy efficiently using some vectorization method? As a side note, I don't mind a solution using Pandas also.

Comment: What's the shape of `embed_vec` in your actual use-case?

Comment: @Divakar : It is `(60000, 3)`

Comment: @Peaceful I deleted the comment because you are using a multi-dimensional distance.  Even though I might try to use some of that logic, this is a distinctly different question

Comment: You can use scipy's [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) to get a distance matrix. May run into memory issues if `tot_vec` is large.

Comment: @kazemakase : I think this should do the job. Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: Someone should really implement something for this.  It has to be about the most asked numpy question.

Comment: @kazemakase : Yes for my array, it says that array is too large.

Comment: @DanielForsman : Completely agreed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Vectorized approach -

```
def vectorized_app(embed_vec, R):  
    tot_vec = embed_vec.shape[0]          
    r,c = np.triu_indices(tot_vec,1)
    subs = embed_vec[r] - embed_vec[c]
    dists = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs)
    return np.bincount(r,dists<R**2,minlength=tot_vec)
```

**Approach #2 :** With less loop complexity (for very large arrays) -

```
def loopy_less_app(embed_vec, R):  
    tot_vec = embed_vec.shape[0]
    Rsq = R**2
    out = np.zeros(tot_vec,dtype=int)
    for i in range(tot_vec):
        subs = embed_vec[i] - embed_vec[i+1:tot_vec]
        dists = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs)
        out[i] = np.count_nonzero(dists < Rsq)
    return out
```

---

## Benchmarking

Original approach -

```
def loopy_app(embed_vec, R):
    tot_vec = embed_vec.shape[0]
    p = np.zeros(tot_vec) # This contains the number of close vectors
    for i in range(tot_vec-1):
        for j in range(i+1, tot_vec):
            if np.linalg.norm(embed_vec[i]-embed_vec[j]) < R:
                p[i] += 1
    return p
```

Timings -

```
In [76]: # Sample random array
    ...: embed_vec = np.random.rand(3000,3)
    ...: R = 0.5
    ...: 

In [77]: %timeit loopy_app(embed_vec, R)
1 loops, best of 3: 50.5 s per loop

In [78]: %timeit loopy_less_app(embed_vec, R)
10 loops, best of 3: 143 ms per loop
```

**`350x+`** speedup there!

Going with much bigger array with the proposed `loopy_less_app` -

```
In [81]: # Sample random array
    ...: embed_vec = np.random.rand(20000,3)
    ...: R = 0.5
    ...: 

In [82]: %timeit loopy_less_app(embed_vec, R)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.47 s per loop
```

Comment: This gives me : `ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
`

Comment: @Peaceful Check out Approach #2 ? That should be good for your `(60000,3)` array, hopefully!

Comment: This is impressive indeed. Can you please explain me how can I modify this for 1d vectors? Because in that case it throws error: `ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string contains too many subscripts for operand 0
`

Comment: @Peaceful For 1D arrays, skip the `einsum` step and at the last step do : `out[i] = np.count_nonzero(np.abs(subs) < R)` for `loopy_less_app` approach.

Comment: If the input array is both 1D and sorted, how could one speed this up further?

Answer (score 2):

I am intrigued by that question and attempted to solve it efficintly using scipy's [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree). However, this approach may run out of memory because internally a list of all pairs with distance <= R is maintained. If your R and tot_vec are small enough it will work:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree

tot_vec = 60000
embed_vec = np.random.randn(tot_vec, 3)
R = 0.1

tree = KDTree(embed_vec, leafsize=100)
p = np.zeros(tot_vec)
for pair in tree.query_pairs(R):
    p[pair[0]] += 1
    p[pair[1]] += 1
```

In case memory is an issue, with some effort it is possible to rewrite `query_pairs` as a generator function in Python at the cost of C performance.

Comment: I was looking into kmeans, but no luck. Good to see it in use for this problem! What about [`count_neighbors`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.count_neighbors.html)?

Comment: @Divakar I guess `count_neighbors` is less efficient because it is meant to operate on two trees and thus might traverse the tree twice. Did not try it, though.

Comment: I see. Not really familiar with kmeans tools :) Would be interesting to see some timings I guess.

Answer (score 0):

first broadcast the difference:

`disp_vecs=tot_vec[:,None,:]-tot_vec[None,:,:]`

Now, depending on how big your dataset is, you may want to do a fist pass without all the math.  If the distance is less than `r`, all the components should be less than `r`

`first_mask=np.max(disp_vec, axis=-1)<r`

Then do the actual calculation

```
disps=np.linlg.norm(disp_vec[first_mask],axis=-1)
second_mask=disps<r
```

Now reassign

```
disps=disps[second_mask]
first_mask[first_mask]=second_mask
```

`disps` are now the good values, and `first_mask` is a boolean mask of where they go.  You can process from there.

Comment: Did you mean to write `embed_vec` in place of `tot_vec`?